# Team Fortress 2 Server Supporter

Tags: team-fortress-2

Whenever you are in the process of connecting to server, there is always a small list of top server supporters, along with a number. What exactly makes someone a "supporter" of a particular server, and what actions move you up in the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list that you see while loading a certain map is the list of people that donated to that map's author, by buying the correspondent map stamp in the Mann Co. in-game store.

Map stamps were introduced during Australian Christmas Update. For more info you can check the official [TF2 Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Map_stamp).

Note that this happens only when loading community created maps. When loading official Valve maps loading screen usually displayed the ladder of mini-duel winners.